# redirecting an entire WP site from one top level domain to another

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I think I know the best way to proceed doing this but just want to get some reassuring thumbs up before going ahead.

Basically I want to move a .co.uk domain to the same name but .com

The site runs on a plesk ubuntu VPS, that lets you change the names of existing domains you have configured, something I was surprised to see it lets you do but it does.

So I plan to rename the domain I have setup from .co.uk to .com and then create a new 2nd domain on the VPS for the .co.uk.   On this I would not need a copy of the WP site, just a blank site in effect with an htaccess that is setup as follows

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Would this command would redirect deep links like for like and are my other assumptions all correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd want a rewrite rule that captures & redirects the *request*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```